# ffmpeg uses all images in a folder even with a -start_number argument

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm having trouble compiling a set of jpeg files in a directory into an mp4 file.  The command I'm using is:

```
./ffmpeg -y -r 20 -i %03d-capture.jpg -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -start_number 10000 video.mp4
```

The folder contains around 20,000 images, and I want a video that starts on the 10,000th image. However, with this command ffmpeg creates a video using all the images in the directory. Is there any reason it would be ignoring the start_number argument?

edit: Figured it out. The -start_number argument needs to come before the -i argument for the input file.  Seems a little silly.

Comment: Placement matters. It isn't silly at all. Options before `-i` (excluding global options) get applied to the input, and options after `-i` get applied to the following output. You can provide an answer so others know you found a solution.

Comment: ...also offtopic (nothing to do with programming). This question should be migrated to [su].